# Why is a Fourier tempered distribution of two sets of coordinates different, when coordinates are shifted on the x-axis?

Tags: fourier-analysis

I have a set of coordinates which I transformed into a real piecewise function. The piecewise function looks as such:

[image]

as you can see, the coordinates are on the interval $[-5,5]$.

When I transform this into a Fourier transform [using tempered distributions](https://math.mit.edu/%7Erbm/iml/Chapter1.pdf), I get:

[image]

as you can see, the peak at zero is reproduced from the piecewisefunction in the Fourier transform. However, the other peaks are symmetrized about the y axis, so they seem to be equalized.

Then, when I shift the coordinates by 5 units on the x-axis, to the interval [0,10] and preserve the y-points,  I get:

[image]

which is the same as plot one, just shifted by 5 units on the x-axis.

Then, when I redo the procedure of Fourier tempered distributions, I get a completely different plot:
[image]

So this is an entirely different function.

If I am interested in the interval to the right of the high peak (at x=0 on the first plot), which of the two plots is the right one, to get a Fourier series of the interval on the right to the high peak at x=0 on top?

If this is not the best way to extract a continuous function that crosses each of the steps of the piecewise function, which method is best?

Thanks

Comment: Unclear what you did and plotted. If $f$ is real valued with Fourier transform $F$ then *obviously* $F(-u) $ is the complex conjugate of $F(u)$.

Comment: It is as you say

Comment: I will do summed Fourier transform, for each wave interval then.